# filter function not working under a function definition in R

Tags: r, filter

I'm trying to delete rows that doesn't have a value from the column "Position_Data".
the below code:
filter(Position_Data != is.na(.))

is getting unexpectedly stuck with the below error message.

Error in `dplyr::filter()`: i
In argument: `Position_Data != is.na(.)`.
Caused by error: ! `..1` must be a logical vector, not a logical matrix.

The below is the complete function that I need to run:
cual_path - it is the path to a csv file that have 20 columns defined under setNames() function

```
read.portfolio <- function(cual_path, quarter_date){
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)
  library(stats)
  library(Hmisc)
  library(tidyverse)
  tenor_vector <- c(1,2,3,4,5,7,10,15,20,25,30)
  portfolio <-  tibble(read.csv(cual_path)) %>% 
    select(-X) %>%  setNames(c("Acct_book_root","AXA_Instrument","ISIN","Ind_Sector","Maturity_Date","Currency",              "Credit_Model_Rating","Issuer_Internal_Rating","Security_Internal_Rating","MV","PV01","CR01","Theo_Delta","Unit_Pos", "Exposure_Pos", "Theo_Exposure", "Unit_Price",
               "Eff_Duration","Eff_Convx","Eff_Spread_Duration")) %>%
    separate(Acct_book_root, c("Col1", "CRDB_Code", "Position_Data"), " >> ") %>%
    select(-Col1) %>%
    filter(Position_Data != is.na(Position_Data)) %>% 
    split(f = as.factor(.$AXA_Instrument)) %>% 
    map(. %>% mutate(Time_to_mat0 = round(interval(ymd(quarter_date),ymd(Maturity_Date)) / years(1), digits = 0)) %>%
          mutate(Time_to_mat = map_dbl(.$Time_to_mat0, function(x) tenor_vector[which.min(abs(tenor_vector - x))])) %>%
          select(-Time_to_mat0))
  return(portfolio)
}
read.portfolio(cual_path, quarter_date = "2022-09-30")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rows that doesn't have a value from the column"? Is it empty, or is it `NA`? If you are removing `NA` you can try with `df %>% drop_na(col)`.

Comment: try `filter(!is.na(Position_Data ))`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I'm trying to remove rows with empty rows in column "Position_Data"

Comment: Thanks Julian, I'm still getting the same error. Strange that the same function code is running correctly for my colleague.